# How do I set relative URLs in an ATDocument using Plone's setText()?

Tags: plone, archetypes

I am trying to write a script to rewrite links in a Plone ATDocument. When I call `getText()` and dereference all the UID links by calling `portal_transforms.convertTo('text/x-html-safe')` the URLs are all rewritten as "http://foo/Plone/..." (literally, "foo", as the domain name). When I save the text with `setText()` and try to view it in the site the "foo" domain name is still there and is not re-written to the correct domain.

How can I make the HTML passed to `setText()` understand links to the current site?

Comment: Is not clear to me how those links are originally composed. Are they internal links that use uids or what?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to modify the value of the text field you need to get the value by using the `raw` getter of the field.

```
>>> item.getRawText()
>>> ...
```

This returns the value `untouched`, then you can modify the text and save it.

NOTE:

> By default plone is using the UID to handle internal links (check linkintegrity feature), so you probably not get a relative path from the raw getter, but a `../resolveuid/$(UID)` like url.

EDIT:

This may help you to rewrite the links.

```
>>> import re
>>> from lxml import html
>>> resolveuid_re = re.compile('^[./]*resolve[Uu]id/([^/]*)/?(.*)$')  # Regex resolving the uid from a path.
```

Get all links from text

```
>>> raw_text = obj.getRawText()
>>> dom = html.fromstring(raw_text)
>>> links = dom.xpath('//a/@href')
>>> links
['resolveuid/fbb9304e48b24a30ac7ba31eb5be2cb6']
```

Get uid(s)

```
>>> uid = resolveuid_re.match(links[0]).group(1)
>>> uid
fbb9304e48b24a30ac7ba31eb5be2cb6
```

Now you may find and replace the uid(s), store them and you're done.

Answer (score 4):

You can also avoid a script and use [rt.bulkmodify](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rt.bulkmodify)

[image: rt.bulkmodify HTML rewrite panel]